# React: export function with connected function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, export, components

I know how to connect my translate function to a component this way:

```
class App extends Component {
...
}
export default translate('common')(App);
```

But how can I do the same task if component is being exported this way:

```
export function UserInterface({data, onAdmin, isAdmin}: propTypes){
...
```

I know, that this is kind of silly question. But I am stuck at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
export const UserInterfaceWithTranslation = translate('common')(UserInterface);
```

Please read more about [exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export).

Comment: Thanks! It really helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can export functions too

**MyContext.js**

```
function UserInterface({data, onAdmin, isAdmin}: propTypes){ 
 ... some code
}

module.exports = {
 userInterface : UserInterface
}
```

**Import**

```
import myContexts from './MyContext'

myContexts.userInterface(params);
```